# How to setup Django inside virtualenv on Windows?

Tags: python, django, windows

Any Windows python developers here?

I created a virtualenv, activated it and installed `django`. If I `run pip3 list`, it shows Django (2.0.3) as installed. The problem is when I try and use django, it never works, it just returns "no module django."

When I try `pip3 install django` again, it says it's already installed at myname\envs...\site-packages. But when I use the django command it never looks at this path, it looks at appdata/local/programs/python/python36-32/python.exe (i.e. not the virtualenv but the python installation itself).

Anyone have any ideas?

Comment: I don't think there is a `django` command, try to run `django-admin` in your **activated django virtual env**

Comment: I tried py -3 -m django --version and with django-admin, neither worked.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you have tried to use pip3 which located in your real python environment. But actually your django has been installed in virtual environment. From your example, maybe you should check the python interpreter something like this: venv/bin/python3.4.

By the way, before you use django-admin command, you should make sure you have already in virtual env.

For example, if you are in virtual env, it will be someting like this:

```
(venv)Mac:myproject michael$ pip install jinja2
...
Successfully installed jinja2-2.7.3 markupsafe-0.23
(venv)Mac:myproject michael$ python myapp.py
...
```

If you want to get into the real python environment:

```
(venv)Mac:myproject michael$ deactivate 
Mac:myproject michael$
```

So, you should make sure you have been in the same environment with both packages and interpreter.

Answer (score 0):

You should use pip after active your virtualenv python environment

Answer (score 0):

Refer to this section of the documentation
https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/intro/contributing/#getting-a-copy-of-django-s-development-version

> For Windows users
>   Using the built-in venv module will not work if you are also using the Git Bash shell on Windows, since activation scripts are only created for the system shell (.bat) and PowerShell (.ps1). Use the virtualenv package instead:

```
$ pip install virtualenv
$ virtualenv ~/.virtualenvs/djangodev
```

Then you start using your virtual environment with

```
workon <<your_virtual_env_name>>
```

Then every package you install will be within this environment